# Tool which can create wadl from existing wsdl?

Tags: wsdl, wadl

I have a question.
I have existing webservices (WSDL/SOAP) and need new REST webservices having the same functions.
Is there an easy way to create a WADL from WSDL?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not included into the distribution jar, tinyWSDL has WSDL 2.0 -> WADL convertor. Obviously the service must be defined using HTTP Binding.
The WSDL 1.1 definitions must be converted into WSDL 2.0 first (also supported by tinyWSDL).

http://sourceforge.net/p/tinywsdl/code/HEAD/tree/TinyWSDLConverter/src/org/inb/bsc/wsdl20/converter/

Cheers,

D.

Answer (score 1):

No.

SOAP and REST are pretty different approaches and this tool would be pretty hard to make or configure. Not saying that these styles cannot be mapped 1:1 to each other, there are things you can make with SOAP and not with REST and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, there are tools like Layer 7 and IBM Datapower, which are designed to do such transformations, but it seems to be, that this tools can't do it automatically.